# Not able to reset show image preview before uploading

Tags: angular

I have html file like follows:

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="file" formControlName="image" (change)="fileProgress($event)">
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="fileUploadProgress">
        Upload progress: {{ fileUploadProgress }}
    </div>
    <div class="image-preview mb-3" *ngIf="previewUrl">
        <img [src]="previewUrl" height="300">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3" *ngIf="uploadFilePath">
        {{ uploadedFilePath}}
```

And my `.ts` file is:

```
this.productForm.reset();
```

I am trying to reset the image upload, but it resets only image file but not photo preview.

Comment: set the previewUrl value to null

Answer (score 0):

You have this parameter `previewUrl` that controls whether to show the preview:

```html
<div class="image-preview mb-3" *ngIf="previewUrl">
```

you need to set it to `undefined` (more typescript than null in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

setting `this.previewUrl = null;` will works in .ts file